# What does "refer to parameters by number instead of by name" in Swift actually does?

Tags: swift

I am new to programming and have learned some basic Python and Java so far. I was hoping to get into Swift so I'm following [Apple's Swift Guided Tour](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/GuidedTour/GuidedTour.html). In the section about functions they said

*"You can refer to parameters by number instead of by name. A closure passed as the last argument to a function can appear immediately after the parentheses. When a closure is the only argument to a function, you can omit the parentheses entirely. "*

Giving an Example as follows:

```
var numbers = [20, 19, 7, 12]
//...
let sortedNumbers = numbers.sorted {$0 > $1}
print(sortedNumbers)  // "[20, 19, 12, 7]\n"
```

But if I try `numbers.sorted()` alone, it will give me the same result.

My question here would be: What exactly is happening in this example code block? Where is the process of executing the program does the lambda function `$0 > $1`? (I think this function as similar to lambda functions in python but I think I might be wrong) What would be a better example to help me understand this?

Comment: Yes. That is like a Python lambda. It Swift they’re call closures. Keep reading. It’s all explained in the chapter about [Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID95)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a perfect answer can be had by reading the well written Swift Language Guide.

Comment: It's like `lambda a, b: b > a` (or in Swift, `{ a, b in b > a }`), except you don't need to come up with names for the params.